# change linq query result value's after performing queries, filters and so on

Tags: linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

i want to change record's in result of linq query. how?

my query :

```
var results = (from myTable in db.MyTable                               
               where //some condition here
               orderby myTable.Count descending
               select new QueryResult()
               {
                   Title = files.Title,
               }).AsQueryable();
```

after performing query, i want to change Title property of QueryResult on each record, but i don't know how?

```
results = results.???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use a [foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) on results

Comment: yes, but there isn't another way to doing this with linq method based queries?

Answer (score 1):

To update the LINQ result using FOREACH loop, I first create **local ‘list’ variable** and then perform the update using FOREACH Loop. The value are updated this way.